# Replace dates in a string to a particular format or a python script to replace digit dates to a particular format

Tags: python, regex, date, datetime, replace

I have a string like the below:

```py
article = "Buy from Australia on 21 august 2019 and deliver it on 29 aug 2019"
```

I want the output as:

```py
article1 = "Buy from Australia on 21/08/2019 and deliver it on 29/08/2019"
```

What i mean is i want to create a python script which will extract any dates out of a string and convert it to a particular format

My approach was to find anydates format but i am stuck after doing that because i am lost on how to replace them

```py
import re

    article = article.replace('jan ', 'january ') #converting the month format
    article = article.replace('feb ', 'february ')
    article = article.replace('mar ', 'march ')
    article = article.replace('apr ', 'april ')
    article = article.replace('may ', 'may ')
    article = article.replace('jun ', 'june ')
    article = article.replace('jul ', 'july ')
    article = article.replace('aug ', 'august ')
    article = article.replace('sep ', 'september ')
    article = article.replace('oct ', 'october ')
    article = article.replace('nov ', 'november ')
    article = article.replace('dec ', 'december ')

if len(re.findall(r"([\d]{1,2}\s(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)\s[\d]{4})", article)) != 0:
        ls3 = re.findall(r"([\d]{1,2}\s(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)\s[\d]{4})", article)
    elif len(re.findall(r"([\d]{1,2}\s(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)\s[\d]{2})", article)) != 0:
        ls3 = re.findall(r"([\d]{1,2}\s(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)\s[\d]{2})", article)
    elif len(re.findall(r"((january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)\s[\d]{1,2}\s[\d]{4})", article)) !=0:
        ls3 = re.findall(r"((january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)\s[\d]{1,2}\s[\d]{4})", article)
    elif len(re.findall(r"([\d]{1,2}-(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)-[\d]{4})", article)) != 0:
        ls3 = re.findall(r"([\d]{1,2}-(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)-[\d]{4})", article)
    elif len(re.findall(r"([\d]{1,2}-(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)-[\d]{2})", article)) != 0:
        ls3 = re.findall(r"([\d]{1,2}-(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)-[\d]{2})", article)
    elif len(re.findall(r"([\d]{1,2}/(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)/[\d]{4})", article)) != 0:
        ls3 = re.findall(r"([\d]{1,2}/(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)/[\d]{4})", article)
    elif len(re.findall(r"([\d]{1,2}/(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)/[\d]{2})", article)) != 0:
        ls3 = re.findall(r"([\d]{1,2}/(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)/[\d]{2})", article)
    elif len(re.findall(r"[\d]{1,2}/[\d]{1,2}/[\d]{4}", article)) !=0:
        ls3 = (re.findall(r"[\d]{1,2}/[\d]{1,2}/[\d]{4}", article))
    elif len(re.findall(r"[\d]{1,2}-[\d]{1,2}-[\d]{4}", article)) !=0:
        ls3 = (re.findall(r"[\d]{1,2}-[\d]{1,2}-[\d]{4}", article))
    elif len(re.findall(r"[\d]{1,2}/[\d]{1,2}/[\d]{2}", article)) !=0:
        ls3 = (re.findall(r"[\d]{1,2}/[\d]{1,2}/[\d]{2}", article))
    elif len(re.findall(r"[\d]{1,2}-[\d]{1,2}-[\d]{2}", article)) !=0:
        ls3 = (re.findall(r"[\d]{1,2}-[\d]{1,2}-[\d]{2}", article))
    elif len(re.findall(r"[\d]{1,2}\s[\d]{1,2}\s[\d]{4}", article)) !=0:
        ls3 = (re.findall(r"[\d]{1,2}\s[\d]{1,2}\s[\d]{4}", article))
    elif len(re.findall(r"[\d]{1,2}\s[\d]{1,2}\s[\d]{2}", article)) !=0:
        ls3 = (re.findall(r"[\d]{1,2}\s[\d]{1,2}\s[\d]{2}", article))

    else:
        ls3 = []
```

Comment: Do these regexps match all the formats you want to support?

Comment: yes, It supports all formats

Comment: You may use a single regex with many capturing groups like [this one](https://regex101.com/r/C0pe40/1) and use a callback method as replacement argument where you may handle the formats as you see fit.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, Can you please help me with the code? for callback

Answer (score 0):

My Answer is as follows: and it worked

```
            if ls3!=[]:
                if isinstance(ls3[0],tuple):
                    ls3 = [i[0] for i in ls3]
                    ls4 = pd.DataFrame(ls3)
                else:
                    ls4 = pd.DataFrame(ls3)


                ls4['1'] = pd.to_datetime(ls4[0])
                ls4['1'] = ls4['1'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

                ls4.columns = ["rpl","rpl1"]

                def find_match(sentence,df):
                    for i in range(df.shape[0]):
                        if sentence.find(df['rpl'][i]) !=-1:
                            sentence = sentence[:sentence.find(df['rpl'][i])] +  df['rpl1'][i] +  sentence[sentence.find(df['rpl'][i])+ len(df['rpl'][i]):]
                    return sentence

                sentence = find_match(article,ls4)
```